# how to use firebase methods in unit testing and widget testing in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, unit-testing

Im writing unit tests and widget tests for my codes , and some files use some of the firebase packages such as :

firebase_core: ^2.8.0
firebase_crashlytics: ^3.0.17
firebase_messaging: ^14.3.0
flutter_local_notifications: ^9.9.1

**and my problem is I cant make them work , or mock them ( I use Mocktail package )for example with this method I fetch some data :

```
class CellInfoRepository implements aaaRepository {
  @override
  Future<Cell?> getCellInfo(int id) async {
    try {
      final response = await aaa().bbb(id);
      return response;
    } catch (e, s) {
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(e, s);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

and this is my test file :

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';
import 'package:firebase_crashlytics/firebase_crashlytics.dart';
import 'aaa';

class Mockaaa extends Mock implements aaa {}

class MockFirebaseCrashlytics extends Mock implements FirebaseCrashlytics {}

void main() {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Firebase.initializeApp();


  late Mockaaa mockApi;
  late MockFirebaseCrashlytics mockCrashlytics;
  late CellInfoRepository repository;

  setUp(() {
    mockApi = Mockaaa();
    mockCrashlytics = MockFirebaseCrashlytics();
    repository = CellInfoRepository();
  });

  test('getCellInfo handles exceptions and returns null', () async {
    when(() => mockApi.Mockaaa(any())).thenThrow(Exception('Failed to fetch data'));

    final result = await repository.getCellInfo(123);

    expect(result, isNull);
    verify(() => mockApi.Mockaaa(123)).called(1);
    verify(() => mockCrashlytics.recordError(any(), any())).called(1);
  });
}
```

the test passes but i got this error :

**Failed to load "/Users/b_test.dart": PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)**

any idea? thanks

tried mocking and faking firebase packages , but didnt work